# Is there a way to see what a Cosmos DB Gremlin API call looks like under the hood?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

If I write: g.V().has("person","name","Diego");
What atom-record-sequence calls are used to make this query work?

Is there a way to directly query the atom-record-sequence in a Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Ms Doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/a-technical-overview-of-azure-cosmos-db/) The core type system of Azure Cosmos DB’s database engine is atom-record-sequence (ARS) based. Atoms consist of a small set of primitive types e.g. string, bool, number etc., records are structs and sequences are arrays consisting of atoms, records or sequences. The database engine of Azure Cosmos DB is capable of efficiently translating and projecting the data models onto the ARS based data model.
The engine is agnostic to the concept of a schema, blurring the boundary between the structure and instance values of records. Cosmos DB achieves full schema agnosticism by automatically indexing everything upon ingestion in an efficient manner, which allows users to query their globally distributed data without having to deal with schema or index management.
The article below explains this pretty well
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/global-dist-under-the-hood